# Presto is giving this error : Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.has(String)" because "currentNode" is null

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, presto, kafka-producer-api

I'm pushing a JSON file into a Kafka topic, connecting the topic in presto and structuring the JSON data into a queryable table.

The problem I am facing is that , presto is not to fetch data its shows error  Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.has(String)" because "currentNode" is null.

Code for pushing data into kafka topic:

```
 object Producer extends App{
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,JsonNode](props)
    println("inside prducer")
    val mapper = (new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper).
        registerModule(DefaultScalaModule).
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false).
        findAndRegisterModules(). // register joda and java-time modules automatically
        asInstanceOf[ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper] 
     val filename = "/Users/rishunigam/Documents/devicd.json"
     val jsonNode: JsonNode=  mapper.readTree(new File(filename))
     val s = jsonNode.size()
     for(i <- 0 to jsonNode.size()) {
    val js = jsonNode.get(i)
   println(js)
  val record = new ProducerRecord[String, JsonNode]( "tpch.devicelog", js)
   println(record)
  producer.send( record )
}
    println("producer complete")
    producer.close()
  
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Did you report this on https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues?

Comment: Would be useful if you added the `devicd.json` file